# Gulp: Do i need the package.json?

Tags: npm, gulp, package.json

Is there any need for the package.json file when I am running a Gulp script?

I just renamed it, and the Gulp-Script is still running - so can I delete it, or is it needed for anything?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you don't need it for gulp.

You do need it for dependency management. If you install gulp plugins with the `--save-dev` flag it will save the dependency for that plugin to `package.json`. If somebody else was to use your code they could just run `npm install` and get all the dependencies you've used at once.